# Best lower bounds on difference between powers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $a,b\in\Bbb N$ be fixed. What are the best known lower bounds on $|a^n-b^m|$ for $n,m\in\Bbb N$, provided the difference is not $0$?

If $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ is rational, then $a,b$ are of the form $c^k,c^l$ for some $c,k,l\in\Bbb N$, hence the difference between $a^n,b^m$ is of exponential size (indeed, I believe it's at least $\min\{a^n,b^m\}$).

The interesting and far less trivial are the bounds when $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ is irrational, e.g. $a=2,b=3$. Using method sketched in [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/) blog post we can prove that for some constants $c,C$ depending on $a,b$ we have $|a^n-b^m|>\frac{c}{m^C}a^n$.

> Is this the best known estimate on $|a^n-b^m|$ known?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be interesting to see such approximations using up to very large $n$ using continued fractions as @EricWong has mentioned. I've looked at it numerically and then graphically for $(a,b)=(2,3)$ and with some examples showing the same *structure* for $b=\{5,7,11\}$ see http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/2hochS_3hochN_V2.htm *(unfortunately I'd inserted some observations in a very unstructured way vears after first version and should rewrite this completely. But it might still give a good impulse)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a certain sense, yes.  Continued fractions provide an infinite number of pairs $m,n$ such that $\big|\frac{\log a}{\log b} - \frac{m}{n}\big| < \frac{1}{n^2}$.  For such pairs we have $$\left|1 - b^m/a^n\right| = \left| 1 - \big(b^{\frac{m}{n} - \frac{\log a}{\log b}}\big)^n\right| = \left| 1 - b^{O(1/n)} \right| = O(1/n),$$
with constants depending on $a,b$.  Thus we already have $|a^n - b^m| < \frac{c}{m} a^n$ for infinitely many values of $m,n$, which is of the same form as stated in your question.  The main difference would seem to be in the value of the exponent $C$, which is related to the [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) of $\log a/\log b$.